# Como importar classe java da pasta src de outro app?

Tags: java, android

Por exemplo, eu tenho vários apps. Todos eles tem na pasta src uma mesma classe java (exemplo: Calculadora.java que é igual para todos). Só que quando modifico esta classe, tenho que copiar a mesma para todas as pastas src de todos apps.

Tem como importar esta classe da pasta src de um determinado app, para todos os outros? Ou ter uma pasta comum (com determinadas classes java comuns) para todos os outros apps?

Comment: Não coloque saudações ou agradecimentos em perguntas ou respostas. Ref: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi vocÊ está querendo criar uma biblioteca - um módulo independente para ser reutilizado por vários aplicativos.

Neste caso você precisará criar um projeto aparte e fazer referência ao projeto compilado em uma determinada pasta.

Para criar um novo módulo de biblioteca no projeto, faça o seguinte:

1. Clique em File > New > New Module.
2. Na janela Create New Module exibida, clique em Android Library e em Next.
3. Atribua um nome à biblioteca, selecione uma versão mínima do SDK para o código na biblioteca e clique em Finish.

Veja as orientações nos links abaixo:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

https://qastack.com.br/programming/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

https://medium.com/android-dev-br/como-criar-suas-pr%C3%B3prias-bibliotecas-b86e4ad77b92

Comment: Gabriel, eu até já tinha usado isto antes (para criar um jar e incluir como biblioteca), mas tinha me esquecido. Realmente é uma opção. Apesar que ainda uso o eclipse...